# Get parameters sent in Apache's HttpPost

Tags: java, android, apache, post

I am sending a json string to my server, sometimes is too much for HttpGet so I am using HttpPost. I added the string data like so:

```
URL Url = new URL(url);
URI uri = new URI(Url.getProtocol(), Url.getHost(),Url.getPath(), Url.getQuery(), null);
Log.i("url_encoded", uri.toString());
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);

List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", touchPointsJSON));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

Log.i("post URI", ""+post.getURI());
client.execute(post);
```

The problem I am encountering is that I cannot see what data was sent in the name value pair after `client.execute(post)`. I want to do this so that I can find out whether the data string was too much even for a POST request.
Any ideas as to how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You can print the namevalue pair like this. Log.v("nameValuePairs ", "" + parameters );